# ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh not functioning

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

We have created an ASP.NET web page and are linking to a deployed SSRS report.  We want to not display the parameter panel but rather pass the parameters programmatically and immediately view the report on the click of a button within the webpage.  The code in the OnClick event is:

```
        protected void btnDECViewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("http://rsreports6-dev.domain.com/ReportServer");
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/NDAR/DataAggregation/DataAgg";

            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[1];
            Param[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Enter_MPIN", "27");

            reportViewer.Visible = true;
            reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
            reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();   
        }
```

The ReportView will hide the parameter pane, but will not display the report.  We have a ScriptManager on the page.  We have tried removing the Refresh command altogether and get the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you getting after the OnClick?

Comment: With the code as is, nothing.  If I change reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true, the reportViewer is displayed with the parameters populated but I have to actually click the View Report button within the reportViewer to generate the report.